# QSS "border-radius" problem on widget when zooming in

Tags: python, pyside2, qtstylesheets

I can't get perfect rounded corners by applying a stylesheet to a widget.
In this case I'm working with a QFrame widget within a QGraphicsScene, but I could recreate the same issue just by applying the same CSS to a QPushButton on a QDialog.
If you zoom in on the widget you'll see the borders are not rounded perfectly and a kind of square shape seems to appear visible on them.

The first picture illustrates this at a scale of 1:1
[image: -]

The second picture shows a closer view on the QFrame widget
[image]

Example:

```
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

view = QtWidgets.QGraphicsView()
scene = QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene()
view.setScene(scene)
view.show()

widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
button = QtWidgets.QFrame(widget)
button.setGeometry(0, 0, 500, 500)
scene.addWidget(widget)

stylesheet = """
QFrame{
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: rgba(10, 10, 10, 255);
    border-width: 16px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    background-color: rgba(61, 72, 81, 255);
}
"""
button.setStyleSheet(stylesheet)
widget.setStyleSheet('background-color: transparent;')
```

I'm testing this within Maya using PySide2.
Any idea if there is a work-around to this issue?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Ever got a solution? I'm having the same issue :(